# Scrape News feed from Bloomberg Terminal

Tags: bloomberg, feed

I have access and am starting to learn how to use the Bloomberg Terminal. My current project requires me to scrape all the news headlines and contents on the Bloomberg Terminal related to a given search criterion, e.g. "NI MICROSOFT". I've already looked at Bloomberg API but it seems to only provide access to market data such as stock/bond quotes, rather than news articles.

I'm quite stuck at the moment and not really sure where I should look for a solution. It would be great if anybody could give me some suggestions!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to subscribe to the EDTF (Event Driven Trading Feed) service over the Api. The service provides realtime updates of Textual News, News Analytics, Corporate Actions, Economic Indicators and more. I'd suggest to contact your terminal sales rep who will connect you to the right team.

Comment: Thank you. I will contact them for further information.