# How to get news feed out of Bloomberg API regarding a particular security(equity) and date range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, sentiment-analysis, bloomberg

I'm working on a project that requires I source news articles from the Bloomberg API regarding a particular security ( say Netflix) within a specific date range. I want to do this in Python and get the news articles in a structure (JSON/XML) format. I believe this can be done using EDTF(Event-Driven Trading Feed) using the Bloomberg Terminal, but I want to do this using the Bloomberg API.

I need these news articles to perform a sentiment-analysis on the articles.

I read the answer to this question: [Scrape News feed from Bloomberg Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547440/scrape-news-feed-from-bloomberg-terminal)

I understand I do have access to EDTF feed but don't know how to get the feed out programmatically in Python as there is really little to no documentation around it. If I could use PDBLP (https://matthewgilbert.github.io/pdblp/api.html), it would be even greater!

Please link some documentation, code examples as to how to go about this problem. If you've worked on a similar project on Bloomberg, it would be great if you could share some code examples. Thank you!